# Ionic Cloud Messaging How to send messages from my own server to specific users?

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, push-notification, ionic2

I have followed this https://docs.ionic.io/services/push/ tutorial and build a client application that can receive push notifications. Sending push notifications done from the Ionic Dashboard now I need to send push notification from my own NodeJS server. (When database insertion happens) and only to specific users.

1. How can I send Push notifications from my server? Is there any API for Ionic Dashboard tool?
2. How to select which users to receive notification? (When my client app register the token with ionic does it needs to send that token to server ? Or is there some other way to do this?)
3. Is there better and free method to send push notifications for Ionic? (I came across Parser which is no longer available)

I was unable to find any tutorials or documentation related to those facts. Please help me.

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? I'm having a similar request. We have backend process that sends SMS when specific "events" happen and need to send that message to mobile devices via push notification as well.